# Why Hindus don't give clothes to the body of dead at time of cremation?

Tags: garuda-purana, cremation

I was in visit to Kerala of my christian friend. There I was asked many questions about Hindu mythology. They asked me

> why we not give any clothes when we cremate anybody.

I had no answer but I gave one common thought that because we are born without clothes. Then again they asked me what does it means that you earn knowledge when you grew. What I want to know *Is there any documentary proof in the scriptures about this*.

Comment: not sure what you mean by 'what does it mean that you earn knowledge when you grew' can you please clarify

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hindu death and cremation rites are fairly standard throughout India.

Christians believe their souls will be reunited with the body at their final judgment, hence they see clothes as important.

Hindus see the body as being returned to the elements as the jiva has left it forever never to be reunited with it again. So clothes are not important. The body is simply wrapped in a white clothes (sometimes orange) as respect, but it no longer holds the jiva.

There are two good articles on Hindu death customs here  -

1. http://www.hinduismtoday.com/modules/smartsection/item.php?itemid=1667

   And
2. http://www.hinduismtoday.com/modules/smartsection/item.php?itemid=5215